# Google Play Release Rollout is Slow

Tags: android, google-play, release, rollout

I have rollout my release at Google Play Console, however after a few days, the rollout percentage is only at 50%. I have set the rollout percentage to 100% since the very beginning. May I know normally how long for Google to rollout 100% and how do I speed up the rollout? Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Just click on `Manage` and then on the next screen click `Update Rollout` button. A popup will appear where you san set rollout to 100%. At the end, don't forget to save the setting.

[image]